# Gitlab pipeline runner exits without error code on npm ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

All of a sudden my gitlab pipeline runners start failing on `npm ci --silent` without an error message.

I've not changed my `package.json` or `package-lock.json` since the last successful run (only a few hours earlier).

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` has stayed the same.

Here is the beginning of my pipeline config, which fails at npm ci --silent:

```
image: 'sleavely/node-awscli:14.x'

stages:
  - deployKrsk
  - runUnitTests
  - testKrsk
  - deployTest
  - deployProd

before_script:
  - npm ci --silent
  - npm install -g typescript
  - npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@8.5.1 --unsafe-perm=true
  - NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max_old_space_size=4096\"
  - node --max-old-space-size=4096

deployKrsk:
  only:
    - master
```

This is a snapshot of the [image: pipeline fails]

Do you have any idea what can cause this failure? I am clueless.

Comment: remove the `--silent` flag and check the logs you might get the issue

Comment: That was the solution. A package that the project depended on had been removed from the npm registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `--silent` flag will suppress output when running npm scripts so you won't get the error logs in case there are any errors. So better to remove and check the logs which will make debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

As @Origin suggested:

Removing the `--silent` flag made the error appear.
In this case a package had been removed from the npm registry but was still present in the dependencies of the project.